# Control order in Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

So I'm creating a little java program with NetBeans' GUI builder. I have a whole bunch of labels (that happen to be icons) on the screen - and occasionally they will be sent to the same exact location. How do I make sure that the label that got sent last, actually displays ontop on the pile of labels? As well as make sure that the mousepress event comes from that top label, not one of the ones underneath?

This is like my 3rd day learning java, so excuse me if it's a dumb question :D

Comment: Learning Java this way would not help your cause, try learning the Basics first.

Comment: *"This is like my 3rd day learning java,.."*  That is way too soon to be getting into Java GUI development.

Comment: I have experience with C#, I have most of the basics down, and I don't want to create a thousand hello world and bicycle class applications, I'd rather just make some actual program and solve problems as they come.

Comment: What you describe above does not sound like an 'actual program'.  In an actual program, one would not typically be stacking labels on top of one another.

Comment: One might if said program is a game. There are ways I could get around it, but I don't see the problem in learning if there's a way to select the order my controls appear in java?

Comment: *"One might if said program is a game."*  Is it a game?  Stop beating about the bush about what 'might' or 'might not' be.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) with setLayout. With that you can stack things over another.

---

Let's assume you are using a JPanel for every "card" of the CardLayout, on which to place the JLabel. Then you need to make the JPanel transparent:

```
jPanel.setOpaque(false);
```

I believe JLabel themselves are already transparent.

Comment: +1, but my reading of the question suggests the OP wants all the labels (or at least whichever parts are not obscured by another icon) visible at the *same time*.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I make sure that the label that got sent last, actually displays ontop on the pile of labels?

Set the ZOrder of the label to zero. The ZOrder controls the order in which components on a panel are painted.

Another approach is to use:

```
panel.add(0, label);
```

This has the same effect as setting the ZOrder when the component is added.